# Glyphicon does not render to the template

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have installed bootstrap in VS Code and imported it to the `styles.css` :

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

I have also checked `package.json` and can see that `"bootstrap": "^4.1.1"` under `dependencies`.
But when I try to render a glyphicon to the template, I get nothing. Here is the code I have in my template: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>` .
Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have dropped `glyphicons` in Bootstrap 4. So you cannot use them.

If you need icons, you have to manually add them to your project.
Download the `Glyphicons` from https://glyphicons.com/ , then add it to `index.html`.

You can get more info here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components

Hope it helps...